# Mask missing from HICON on Win10 but not Win7

Tags: winapi, xojo

I am trying to use some system icons such as `SIID_DOCNOASSOC` and `SIID_FOLDER` and draw them.

I have the problem that while my code works as expected in Windows 7, on Windows 10 the retrieved images are missing their mask. I cannot figure out why (the `PICONINFO.hbmMask` field that I can retrieve with `GetIconInfo` is non-null, indicating that there is a mask, indeed).

My code is written in Xojo, which uses a dialect of VB, but that should hardly matter, as I got it working in Win 7, I'd think:

```
dim info as SHSTOCKICONINFO
info.cbSize = SHSTOCKICONINFO.Size
SHGetStockIconInfo (SIID_DOCNOASSOC, SHGSI_ICON, info)

dim iconHandle as Integer = info.hIcon
dim destDC as Integer = ... // intialized outside
DrawIconEx (destDC, 0, 0, iconHandle, 0, 0, 0, 0, DI_MASK)
```

The above code fetched the icon for a plain file and then draws its mask. While the mask is correct on Win 7, the mask is all black over the entire icon's area on Win 10.

Why would that happen?

Comment: You seem to ignore return values, so have no error checking

Comment: Win10 is more likely to be the 64-bit version so a pinvoke declaration mistake can easily byte.  It also isn't obvious whether this is the same icon, Win10 will use a lot more of the fancier icons.  The one that embed a PNG image and have no mask.  None is needed since PNG already supports transparency.

Comment: [The evolution of the ICO file format, part 4: PNG images](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101022-00/?p=12473).

Comment: Side question: I only seem to be getting rather low-res icons (32x32) from SHGetStockIconInfo. How would I get the high-res icons available in Win 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Windows XP added support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101021-00/?p=12483/) for 32-bit ARGB icons with alpha transparency. These icons still contain a black and white mask bitmap but it is often not correct, it depends on the icon editor used and how the artist drew the image! They often look like the my documents icon in [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9142/Adding-and-using-bit-alphablended-images-and-ic).

[Vista added support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101022-00/?p=12473) for PNG images in icons (often called "compressed" in icon editors) and contain no mask bitmap. It is not documented what `GetIconInfo` does to create the mask for these.

The days of playing with HICON masks are long gone, if you want to draw a icon you should let windows do it for you without extracting the parts of a HICON. `ImageList_DrawEx` has some blending support if you need it.

If you absolutely need a mask for some reason then you should build it yourself when the icon contains alpha transparency. Pick some sort of threshold (25, 50, whatever) and treat everything higher than that as transparent when you inspect the alpha values.

Comment: I do need to post process the icon in Xojo's environment, so I need to be able to draw it into Xojo's Picture object, e.g. with DrawIcon - and since Xojo does not support alpha channel on Windows, yet (but only separate img+mask), I'll have to extract the mask separately. Thanks for providing some background information and more suggestions to solve this. I'll look into them later.

Comment: Okay, with your indication of using alpha instead of mask I solved it with Xojo now, too. Turns out that recent Xojo versions suddenly do support alphas and seem to have broken mask handling along the way. After rewriting my code, I can now use the simpler DrawIcon method to draw the icon into a Picture object without needing to separate picture and mask, and that got rid of the issue with Win 10.

Comment: Looking at the article, I wonder how I can get the hi-res stock icons for file, folder, disk etc? SHGetStockIconInfo only seems to give me the classic 16x16 and 32x32 sizes. I searched SO for solutions but only nothing on getting modern hi-res versions of these stock icons that File Explorer uses.

Comment: Are you usingDrawIconEx? Plain DrawIcon only draws small icons. Alternatively you can use SHGSI_ICONLOCATION (and then call LoadImage) or SHGSI_SYSICONINDEX (and the jumbo imagelist). Most of the icons are available in 256x256 versions.